# Passing integer value in C module

Tags: c

i would like to pass the integer value in the module. following is my C code;

```
 int i;
 SYMBOL di;
 di   = symbol_CreateStandardVariable();
```

and the module is

```
 t = term_Create(Door,list_Cons(term_Create(di, list_Nil()), list_List(term_Create(di, list_Nil()))));
```

is there any way so that i can pass the value like d1, d2 , d3 ... iteratively and pass in the module in place of di?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this code intended to do?

Comment: At the end of the day, this program gets new standard variable for every new input symbol. So as to make the symbol different,i need to pass different symbols. thus for passing differnet variable i thought of changing the numerical value by iterations.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to iterate the variables `d1`, `d2`, `d3` in sequence, based on the name of the variable and the value of `i`.

So, while you cannot do that directly, it sounds like what you are looking for is a [for loop](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-for-loop-statement.aspx) that loops over an [array](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-arrays.html).

Comment: i mean i want to replace the di with iterations  by d1,d2 and so on. yes that is loop over array. I didn't get perfect idea for it too,may be due to lack of strong command over C. can you please help me out?